# Is it correct to have two dependent clauses and one independent clause?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> I am now trying new things, including this blog, a thank you to
>   all those who helped me get to where I am today by sharing their
>   stories, and my way of paying it forward by sharing my stories.

How wrong is the above sentence? Can I fix it by putting a "which is" between "blog" and "a thank you", should I remove the last comma? Or is this just a dumpster sentence? Or is it actually grammatically correct/gray?

What I think I see is one independent clause followed by three dependent clauses, two of which are dependent on the first dependent clause. I see rules about one independent clause and one dependent, and two independents and multiple dependents, but still nothing about one independent with multiple dependents.

https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentences.htm

Edit:

I ended up editing it to be

> I am now trying new things, including this blog. I
>   hope that by sharing my stories and lessons learned along the way,
>   this blog will help you in the same way that thousands of internet
>   strangers unknowingly helped me with their stories and comments.

I think this is more correct but I'm still curious about the validity of the first example, if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am now trying new things, including this blog, a thank you to all those who helped me get to where I am today by sharing their stories, and my way of paying it forward by sharing my stories.

Without looking up the official grammatical rules, personally, I would feel much better about this:

> I am now trying new things, including this blog—a thank you to all those who helped me get to where I am today by sharing their stories; it is my way of paying it forward by sharing my stories.